# How can I make a clickable word/cell in the terminal/cmd using python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on an IDLE/RPG game which will work on the Terminal/CMD, my problem is that I need the user to click on text/cells to render the game a bit more practical.

For example, instead of typing O/n and then click enter, I want him to be able to click on the text shown or on a specific cell. I searched for almost two days and still not found any clue about it. I am using PyCharm on Windows 10 Family.

[image]

Comment: [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), it seems, has built-in support for capturing mouse events.

Comment: I found out about curses, but the mouse events are, i think, taken from the coordinates of the entire screen and not just the window, wich involves that if the user moves the window to elsewhere the coordinates of a specific cell will be rendered false. But i'll search more about the curses mouse events. Thanks for the help ! Have a good day ^^!

Comment: Maybe ask the user to "calibrate" the mouse by clicking into two positions at opposite corners of the window when the game starts. Or maybe just convert the whole thing to a GUI app...

Comment: Thanks, i'll do as you said : creating a GUI app like the terminal/cmd and then implement the functions I said on the main question !